# cssRules[x].selectorText in IE9 not working/undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, webpack

So I have a function that searches cssRules so we can get access to the style object in the javascript:

```
getCSSRule: function(selector) {
    var i, j, sheet;
    if (selector in this.cssCache) {
        return this.cssCache[selector];
    }
    for (i in document.styleSheets) {
        sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        for (j in sheet.cssRules) {
            if (sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText === selector) {
                this.cssCache[selector] = sheet.cssRules[j];
                return sheet.cssRules[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Chrome this works fine, but in IE9 `selectorText` is undefined and I also see `UNKNOWN_RULE: 0`.

I found this on the web from [here](http://javascript.nwbox.com/CSSSupport/):

> On IE browsers up to the latest IE8 when a rule is inserted in the stylesheet, it produces two changes in the parsed output: a) the selectorText property is set to the upper case string 'UNKNOWN' if it is invalid, b) the representation read back from the stylesheet cssText have properties with upper case names if they are recognized, or they are discarded from the representation if unknown to the parser.

However, I don't really understand what the issue is or how to fix it. FYI the stack is React, ES6, and webpack which is also handling importing the scss into the javascript modules which are inserted at run time in style tags.

Comment: it means IE9 doesn't know how to handle the selector and/or rule. you can use `rules[i].cssText` to get the whole text, then split(), `("{")[0]` to get the selector text without using the `selectorText`.